# How can i create custom Validation in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages, customvalidator

I have the following code to Validate the users input to check if data exist in the database when user enters new record if record exist display validation error

Here is what i used currently it works but i need your help creating a custom validation using the same logic

How can i implement the logic added in my action using Custom Validation?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Contact contactToCreate)
    {
      var ProductCodeRange = await ContactsService.GetContactsByProductCodeByType(
                contactToCreate.ProductCodeRangeFrom.Value,
                contactToCreate.ProductCodeRangeThru.Value,
                contactToCreate.ProductCode.Value,
                contactToCreate.TypeID);

      if (!ModelState.IsValid || (ProductCodeRange != null && (contactToCreate.ProductCodeRangeFrom != null && contactToCreate.ProductCodeRangeThru != null)))
            {
            if (ProductCodeRange != null && (contactToCreate.ProductCodeRangeFrom != null && contactToCreate.ProductCodeRangeThru != null))                
                     ModelState.AddModelError("ProductCode", "The Product Code already Exist");
                return View();
            }

     ...

}
```

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk Its added in my question, need help implementing the logic added in my action using Custom Validation

Comment: Why not use `if (ProductCodeRange != null) { ModelState.AddModelError ... }` ? Why do yo check every property of `contactToCreate` twice?

Comment: @RomanMarusyk good question, I have public int? ProductCode { get; set; } in my model and i get this InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value. when its null because sometimes product code is null sometime not. ProductCode is null that means i am using ProductcodeRange